# In short, I can't seem to download or install most things on my Win7 Lappy from Chrome...as well as the whole system just being slow

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, performance, connection, throttling

I have a Toshiba Satellite with Win7. At first I started noticing videos playing slower. At my boyfriends place it was less noticeable since the internet speed was cranked up pretty high and we lived right in town but at my parents, which is where I'm at now it's really noticeable since they live in the middle of nowhere and on the outskirts of their provider. So, to watch an hour long video take almost twice as long for it to buffer or just completely give up. My CPU stays under 5% most of the time and my RAM about 20%-40% depending on what I'm running.

I use Chrome and have disabled all my addons, cleared cookies, and all that jazz. After doing that, I ran AVG. No change in performance. I've opened task manager and ended processes like itunes updaters and java updaters... I've ran the disk and defrag cleaners that come on the computer. I've tried setting the processes that I want to use to a higher priority. I've uninstalled all the extra programs and games that I'm not using...

Still, none of the videos that I try watching run anywhere near expected even when every other electronic is off and my lappy is the only one on wifi.

Well, to see if maybe there was something I was missing I tried downloading Avast. I've read a bunch of reviews saying it was decent and picks up a bunch of things other programs miss. This is where my second problem came in.

I either get an Unknown Network Error and the download fails or it just doesn't do anything. You can watch the kbs/s drop from like 50 to 0 where it will stay.
A few downloads did make it through and on them when I tried installing them is when I had the same problem of the program just "freezing up".

I don't know much about computers and I'm hesitant to mess with too many settings for fear of breaking my only PC.

I'll give you screenshots of any stats you want to look at.

I've read many other posts about similar cases to mine but none really seemed to be exactly what I needed. I'd follow some of the advice from them and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if Windows suddenly slows down, there will be one of 2 main reasons. Either you have a disk error that the system is trying to work around or you have malware installed.

Start by checking your browsers to see if any unwanted addins are present.

Next, look in Task Manager to see if there are any processes or services running that you don't recognise, look these up online to see if any of them are malware.

Next, download a couple of anti-malware tools (not just anti-virus), for example:

- http://www.superantispyware.com/ (use the portable version)
- http://www.malwarebytes.org (uninstall afterwards)

And check to see if you have any unwanted "visitors".

Also check the event log for any odd errors.

Let us know if anything shows up, or indeed if it doesn't show up. We may be able to help and guide further.